How can I processing a CSV file using RabbitMQ
I have a CSV file in the root of the project, in the /uploads folder. I want this file to be split into 2 queues and sent to RabbitMQ for processing. How can this be implemented?

You can use the existing infraestructure on Magento for this.
Generate a custom module in your Magento setup. Let’s name it Vendor/QueueProcessor.

Create the following folder structure:
app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor


Add module.xml under app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor/etc:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_QueueProcessor" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>


Add registration.php in app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor:
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_QueueProcessor',
    __DIR__
);



Create a CsvProcessor.php file inside app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor/Model/:
<?php

namespace Vendor\QueueProcessor\Model;

class CsvProcessor
{
    protected $fileDirectory;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->fileDirectory = BP . '/uploads/'; // Assuming the file is stored in the /uploads folder
    }

    public function splitCsv($fileName)
    {
        $filePath = $this->fileDirectory . $fileName;
        $csvData = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filePath));

        // Split the CSV rows into two parts
        $half = ceil(count($csvData) / 2);
        $firstHalf = array_slice($csvData, 0, $half);
        $secondHalf = array_slice($csvData, $half);

        return [$firstHalf, $secondHalf];
    }
}

RabbitMQ is configured in Magento’s queue.xml , so we configure two queues.

Create a queue.xml under app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor/etc:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue/etc/queue.xsd">
    <queue name="queue_1" connection="amqp"/>
    <queue name="queue_2" connection="amqp"/>
</config>



if RabbitMQ is not already configured, add the RabbitMQ configuration in env.php:
'queue' => [
    'amqp' => [
        'host' => 'rabbitmq',
        'port' => '5672',
        'user' => 'guest',
        'password' => 'guest',
        'virtualhost' => '/'
    ]
],

Create a QueuePublisher.php class to send messages to RabbitMQ.
In app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor/Model/QueuePublisher.php:
<?php

namespace Vendor\QueueProcessor\Model;

use Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherInterface;

class QueuePublisher
{
    protected $publisher;

    public function __construct(PublisherInterface $publisher)
    {
        $this->publisher = $publisher;
    }

    public function publishToQueues($firstBatch, $secondBatch)
    {
        // Publish first batch to queue_1
        foreach ($firstBatch as $message) {
            $this->publisher->publish('queue_1', json_encode($message));
        }

        // Publish second batch to queue_2
        foreach ($secondBatch as $message) {
            $this->publisher->publish('queue_2', json_encode($message));
        }
    }
}

For running all of this, implement a custom CLI command to process the CSV file and publish it to RabbitMQ. This allows you to trigger the job manually for testing.
Create a ProcessCsvCommand.php in app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor/Console/Command/:
<?php

namespace Vendor\QueueProcessor\Console\Command;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Vendor\QueueProcessor\Model\CsvProcessor;
use Vendor\QueueProcessor\Model\QueuePublisher;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class ProcessCsvCommand extends Command
{
    protected $csvProcessor;
    protected $queuePublisher;
    protected $appState;

    public function __construct(
        CsvProcessor $csvProcessor,
        QueuePublisher $queuePublisher,
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->csvProcessor = $csvProcessor;
        $this->queuePublisher = $queuePublisher;
        $this->appState = $appState;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('queueprocessor:processcsv')
            ->setDescription('Process CSV and send to RabbitMQ queues.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml'); // Set app state to avoid issues

        // Process CSV
        list($firstHalf, $secondHalf) = $this->csvProcessor->splitCsv('file.csv');

        // Publish to queues
        $this->queuePublisher->publishToQueues($firstHalf, $secondHalf);

        $output->writeln('CSV processed and messages sent to RabbitMQ queues.');
    }
}

Add the command to your module’s di.xml in app/code/Vendor/QueueProcessor/etc/:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Symfony\Component\Console\Command\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="queueprocessor:processcsv" xsi:type="object">Vendor\QueueProcessor\Console\Command\ProcessCsvCommand</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>

After deploying the module and running Magento setup, you can now process the CSV and send the data to RabbitMQ:
php bin/magento queueprocessor:processcsv

Based on what is needed to be done with the messages or the format, the processing of the messages can be a different story.
